# Update PowerBI datasource parameters programatically using PBI API

Tags: azure-table-storage, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource, powerbi-api

I would like to update my datasource credentials to AzureTable Storage.

To know how is the format of the credentials I maked a [Get datasources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/getdatasources) infos on an existing already linked dataset ( via power bi desktop )

```
{
    "@odata.context": "http://wabi-west-europe-b-primary-redirect.analysis.windows.net/v1.0/myorg/groups/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/$metadata#datasources",
    "value": [
        {
            "datasourceType": "AzureTables",
            "connectionDetails": {
                "account": "storageName",
                "domain": "table.core.windows.net"
            },
            "datasourceId": "1a2bd852-8447-440b-b1c6-xxxxxxxxxx",
            "gatewayId": "4aa719f9-565e-450b-b6a6xxxxxx"
        }
    ]
}
```

So I tried to use the same structure to push a new dataset linked to this datasource using [push API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/pushdatasets/datasets_postdatasetingroup#datasetmode)

Here's my request body

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "defaultMode": "Push",
    "tables": [],
    "datasources": 
        {
            "datasourceType": "AzureTables",
            "connectionDetails": {
                "account": "prodcallrecord",
                "domain": "table.core.windows.net"
            },
            "datasourceId": "1a2bd852-8447-440b-b1c6-xxxxxxx",
            "gatewayId": "4aa719f9-565e-450b-b6a6-xxxxxxxxx"
        }
    
}
```

Unfortunately I get this error

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "InvalidRequest",
        "message": "TOM deserialization failed for database sobe_wowvirtualserver|796c45fc-7f73-4711-a380-81465baedba7, Exception: <pi>Unrecognized JSON property: datasources. Check path 'datasources', line 1, position 60.</pi>"
    }
}
```

I don't know where I've messed , is it because AzureTable is not supported by PowerBI API ?

Is there another way to do this ?